# condition for a set to be finite given a map between this set and a finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ is a finite set. Consider the set $Y$. If we find a surjection $f: X \to Y $, does it follow that $Y$ is also a finite set ?

Comment: Yes. You may want to use the "finite" choice (can be proved by induction) to prove "surjective implies right-invertible" in the finite case. In the end you get an injection from $Y$ to $X$ whose range is finite (since it's a subset of finite set, namely $X$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.
 By definition of function for each $x\in X$ there is only one $y\in Y$ such that $y=f(x)$. so the number of elements of $Y$ is less than or equal to the number of elements of $X$. (because of surjection).

Comment: Great! I am trying to show that if $G$ is a finite group, then $G/H $ must be finite two, where $G/H$ is the set of cosets of $H$: If I define a map $f: G \to G/H $ by $f(g) = gH $, then is $f$ surjective ?

Comment: yes it is surjective

Comment: G/H must be finite *too*

Comment: because $f$ is surjective, then $G/H$ must be finite correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As $f$ is a surjection, for every $y\in Y$ there is a $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$. Hence, $|Y|\leq|X|$ and $Y$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $X$ is finite and $f:X\to Y$ is surjective, then show that $|X|\ge |Y|$.